# How can we get path to server for storing images in /images folder in java?

Tags: java, spring

How can we get path for storing images in server and is it good approach to use getRealPath(String path) method or can any one suggest me what is good approach to store images?

Comment: You shouldn't mix your application and the Content. Think about what will happend, when you deploy a new Version or simply restart the server

Comment: Yes thats what i am looking for. Is there any better approach for that?

Comment: You pick a location on your server, where you have the appropriate permissions, and just use that as path.

Comment: Can you give small example of getting path to that folder and accessing it by url? for example i want to store images in /images folder now how can i get that path to the images folder in server? Assume that i have given permission to access that !